Hyperbolic Primality Test
I came across the article titled Hyperbolic Primality Test and Catalan–Mersenne Number Conjecture.
I tried to implement their Hyperbolic Primality Test:
If there exists a non-trivial $x$ satisfying
$$ 2^{p-1} + x \equiv 0 \pmod{2x+1} \text{,} $$
then $2^p - 1$ is prime.
Here, the trivial solutions are $x = 0$ and $2^{p-1} - 1$.
My implementation is written in C using libgmp.
The problem is, whenever I found $x$ satisfying the above congruence, $2^p - 1$ is composite (not a prime number, as the article claims).
Can you try it too, to see if I made a mistake somewhere?
Or is there a mistake in the article?
Any feedback is welcome.

There's an obvious typo - it should say "no nontrivial" vs. "a nontrivial". I removed some tags since this has nothing to do with them - it is simply a rephrasing of the definition of a prime in the odd case - see my answer.  Beware that there are many very low quality papers on preprints.org. $\ \ $

It's trivial:$ $ put $\,a = 2^{p-1}\,$ in this rewriting of the definition of an odd prime $\,q=2a-1$:
$\quad\begin{align}{2a-1}\ {\rm is\ prime}&\iff (2x+1\mid \color{#0a0}{2a-1}\,\Rightarrow\, 2x+1 = 2a-1\,\ {\rm or}\,\ 1)\\[.4em]
&\iff \bbox[3px,border:1px solid #c00]{2x+1\mid \,\color{#0a0}{a\,+\,x} \,\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \  x\ =\ a-1\ \ \ {\rm or}\ \ \  0\,}
\end{align}$
because  $\bmod 2x\!+\!1\!:\  \color{#0a0}{2a\equiv 1\!\iff\! a\equiv -x}\,$ (by scaling by $\,2^{-1}\equiv -x,\,$ by $\,2(-x)\equiv 1)$.

Or $\large \ 2^{-1}\equiv -x,$ so $\large ,\color{#0a0}{2^{-1}\equiv a\iff a\equiv -x}, $ by uniqueness of inverses, is a bit more conceptual. Such uniqueness often leads to slick proofs, e.g. see here. $\ \ $

It seems there is a typo in the article. It likely meant instead something like that if there are no (rather than "a") non-trivial $x$ satisfying the specified congruence equation, then $2^p-1$ is prime. This is also suggested in the article text where, between its equations $(5)$ and $(6)$, it states that

So, if there exists any integer lattice point on the hyperbola, $M_p$
is not prime.

There's a fairly simple and direct way to show this compared to what's used in the linked article. Since $\gcd(2, 2x + 1) = 1$ (so $2^{-1} \equiv x + 1 \pmod{2x + 1}$), we have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2^{p-1} + x & \equiv 0 \pmod{2x+1} \iff \\
2^{p} + 2x & \equiv 0 \pmod{2x+1} \iff \\
2^{p} - 1 & \equiv 0 \pmod{2x+1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
If $2^{p} - 1$ is prime, then the only positive values of $2x + 1$ which work are $2x + 1 = 1 \;\to\; x = 0$ and $2x + 1 = 2^{p} - 1 \;\to\; x = 2^{p-1} - 1$, i.e., what are considered to be the trivial solutions. Thus, if there are any non-trivial solutions, then $2^p - 1$ cannot be prime, i.e., it's composite as you've determined. In particular, each factor of $2^p - 1$, with $1 \lt f \lt 2^p - 1$, has a solution of $f = 2x + 1$ (e.g., for $p = 4$ with $2^4 - 1 = 15$, we have the solutions of $2x + 1 = 3$ (so $x = 1$) and $2x + 1 = 5$ (so $x = 2$)).

This has nothing to do with integers of the form $,2^p-1.,$ Rather it simply a trivial rewriting of the definition of an odd prime (irreducible) integer, as I explain in my answer.
